# Syntax error: Invalid table specification

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, syntax-error

While retrieving data from Sage 50 i get this error. I googled it but I can't find anything. Logically I thought that my table names where wrong in my SQL query but I think they are not. I can't see the database because it's an external program.

The error is:

> *Syntax error: Invalid table specification*

Has anyone encountered the same problem?When I run following code:

```
String query = "SELECT TRAN_NUMBER,PAID_FLAG,AUDIT_USAGE.DATE, AUDIT_USAGE.DELETED_FLAG "
                + "FROM AUDIT_SPLIT FULL "
                + "OUTER JOIN AUDIT_USAGE ON AUDIT_USAGE.REFERENCE = AUDIT_SPLIT.INV_REF "
                + "AND AUDIT_USAGE.SPLIT_NUMBER = AUDIT_SPLIT.TRAN_NUMBER "
                + "WHERE NOMINAL_CODE = 2401 and AUDIT_SPLIT.DETAILS NOT LIKE 'Deleted%'";
```

I get following Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Invalid table specification
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.run_005fgovlevy_jsp._jspService(run_005fgovlevy_jsp.java:90)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which table store NOMINAL CODE column?

Comment: Change query like following    String query = "SELECT TRAN_NUMBER,PAID_FLAG,AUDIT_USAGE.DATE, AUDIT_USAGE.DELETED_FLAG "
                + "FROM AUDIT_SPLIT AS FULL "
                + "OUTER JOIN AUDIT_USAGE AU ON AU.REFERENCE = AS.INV_REF "
                + "AND AU.SPLIT_NUMBER = AS.TRAN_NUMBER "
                + "WHERE NOMINAL_CODE = 2401 and AS.DETAILS NOT LIKE 'Deleted%'";

Comment: Note that the WHERE conditions make the outer join execute as a regular join. Move those to the ON clause instead to get a real FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: AUDIT_SPLIT, I've exported Sage DB to excel but it does not show the table names.

Comment: @ Afsun Khammadli. Tried it but same error coming up.

Comment: Please post full stackstrace

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And why are you using the deprecated, slow and buggy ODBC bridge?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL. I'm using the ODBC bridge because that's what was provided to me by the Sage company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a query that works on multiple tables, so I queried the data in each table and saved it to my local server and the used the query above and it worked fine.

Comment: I know this is a very old post but I thought I'd just throw in a comment for future visitors. I'm currently having this same issue and it appears it doesn't like joining to multiple tables. I can join to one table and it's fine, but not multiple. Looks like a work around is as described here.

Answer (score 0):

At least in ANSI SQL `DATE` is a reserved word. Double quote it:

```
SELECT TRAN_NUMBER, PAID_FLAG, AUDIT_USAGE."DATE" ...
```

Comment: No difference, same exception